# Generic variable to reference for Array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, reference, swift4

I have two arrays, [String] and [UIImage]. Is there a way to make a variable that can reference both arrays. Something similar to the objc code below but in Swift.

```
    NSArray *images;
    NSArray *strings;
    NSarray *reference;

    //...some other work

    if(someBoolFlag){
        reference = images;
    } else {
        reference = strings;
    }
```

The reason is because I have a class that displays images (Something like a image gallery class) that accepts list of images OR list of strings(URL) during init. I tried using [Comparable] and [Equatable] but its giving me "Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" error. I using Array but still I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You're asking the Y question: "How can I have a variable that can either stores a `[String]` or a `[UIImage]`", but I think you should investigate the X question: Why does the image gallery class accept either, and can that be fixed?

Comment: @Alexander Yes I can modify the parameters for the class. For now i just need to know the count of the items, be it string or image. So my current solution is var count:Int to hold the array count and will be assign during init as well. But I'm wondering if its possible to convert of the above code to swift.

Comment: You can convert the code, in a superficial sense, by using a protocol (like Renato's `ShowImage`, or less preferably `Any`), but the main issue here is that Swift and Objective C just have a fundamental philosophical difference. `NSArray` contains objects of an unspecified type. Can be `NSNull`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`, whatever. `NSArray` doesn't care, which comes at the cost of making it less safe (you always have to be making sure you don't misinterpret object types)

Comment: @Alexander I am checking the link he provided. I am looking to it right now. Thanks mate! :)

Comment: I agree with @Alexander It is the very static nature of swift and how it handles generics vs Objective-Cs very dynamic type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with a protocol abstract away the part of getting the image. Something like this (not really beautiful but should work):

```
protocol ShowImage {
    func showImage() -> UIImage
}

extension String: ShowImage {
    func showImage() -> UIImage {
        // Get image from web
        return UIImage(named: "image-from-web")!
    }
}

extension UIImage: ShowImage {
    func showImage() -> UIImage {
        return self
    }
}

let strings: [ShowImage] = ["URL1", "URL2"]
let images: [ShowImage] = [UIImage(named: "image-1")!]
var reference: [ShowImage]?

var flag = false
if (flag) {
    reference = strings
} else {
    reference = images
}
```

Btw: You cannot use Comparable and Equals because they have Self constraints. To have arrays of protocols with Self constraints you have to apply something like type erasure. Check this out: https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/

Comment: I think I looking for something like this. I'll check out the link. Thanks!

Comment: It really didn't come to my mind to use protocol with my current problem. But this really made me re-think my architecture. Accepted as answer. Thanks @Renato!

Comment: No worries @TheNitram Glad this gave you a hint :)

Comment: Although my example works, it does not mean you should copy past it :) Try to rethink your current approach. If you have your code somewhere on github or alike I can take a look at your solution afterwards :)

Comment: I didn't use it. But it gave me an idea how to use it to further suit my case. The link you provided led me to another link I had stop what I'm doing to learn more about this. Thanks again for the help! (Y)